# Passing Rails form input as string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a rails form that uses a GET request to submit data.  I have a select_tag option, which essentially gives the user a list of options where they can select multiple.  This data is then submitted through the URL as an array, which is very ugly and long.  Is there a way to instead call a join and submit this data as a string?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is create a hidden input field and then take over form submission in javascript and pull the data from your select field, do your join magic and store that data in a hidden field.

For example, in HAML:

```
= form_tag your_path, :id=> "your-form", :method => :post do
  = select_tag "your-options", "<option>Option1</option><option>Option2</option><option>Option3</option>"
  %input(type="hidden" id="select_data" name="select_data" value="")

:javascript
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#your-form').submit(function(){
     data = getDataFromYourSelectFieldAndJoinItIntoAString();
     //store in hidden field
     $('#select_data').val(data);
     //clear options selection
     $('#your-options').val('');
     return true;
   });
 });
```